# copying file download data using curl in buffer

Tags: curl, buffer, memcpy

I am writing simple program below to download the data mentioned in url.
 I want to copy the data into a buffer and don't want to use the for loop
 as is happening now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
string data; //will hold the url's contents
char *bufnew;

size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void*    up)
{ 
   printf("size  = %d\n\n\n",size);
   printf("size nmemb  = %d\n\n\n\n\n",nmemb);
   //memcpy(bufnew,buf,nmemb);
   for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
   {
       data.push_back(buf[c]);
   }
   return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
}

int main()
{
   CURL* curl; //our curl object
   char url_firstpart[80];// = NULL;
   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
   curl = curl_easy_init();

   strcpy(url_firstpart,"http://www-itec.uni-   klu.ac.at/ftp/datasets/mmsys12/Valkaama/valkaama_1s");
   strcat(url_firstpart,"valkaama_1s_50kbit/valkaama_1s1.m4s");

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,url_firstpart);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); 
   curl_easy_perform(curl);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   curl_global_cleanup();
   return 0;
}
```

In write_callback function all the data that is getting downloaded is in   buf and it is copied in data in for loop.I want to avoid this for loop and copy the whole data in some other buffer.How can i do that.If i am doing memcpy its giving me segmentation fault.

Also if the write_callback function is called multiple times how can i append the buffer from second iteration to the buffer at first iteration and so on.
Please guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to append the buffer to the `std::string` you can use [append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) like this :

```
size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void*    up)
{ 
   data.append(buf, size*nmemb);
   return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
}
```

In order to use different buffer, you could use the `void *up` instead of the global variable `data`

To use memcpy, you should allocate the `bufnew` before making the copy.